# Display group mean values legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I managed to create overlaying density plots, separated by color, with the legend outside of the graph with the corresponding grouping/color. Each density plot displays the mean with a vertical dashed line. I also would like to display in a legend, inside the graph, the corresponding value of each mean associated by the same color (if possible).

I adapted `mtcars` in order to be able to show what I want to do.

```
 df2 <-mtcars
    df2 <- df2 %>% add_column(Cyl =
                              case_when(df2$cyl == 6 ~ "Six", 
                                        df2$cyl == 8 ~ "Eight",
                                        df2$cyl == 4 ~ "Four"), .after = "cyl")

mu_hp_cyl<- ddply(df2, "Cyl", summarise, grp.mean=mean(hp)) 
head(mu_hp_cyl)

hp_cyl<-ggplot(df2, aes(x=hp, color=Cyl)) +
  geom_density()+
  geom_vline(data=mu_hp_cyl, aes(xintercept=grp.mean, color=Cyl),
             linetype="dashed") +
  labs(x = 'Hp by Cylinder', y = 'Density')
hp_cyl
```

I tried adding each mean value individually with `geom_text`, but then the values are too large. I also tried adding the variable I created "`mu_hp_cyl`", but I get an error saying the value needs to be either 1 or the total length of the data.

I have some packages loaded by I believe this requires `ggplot2` and `dplyr`.

Any help is appreciated!

p.s. first time posting, apologies for any mistakes in formatting.

Comment: This is a good first question, don't worry! I think it would be useful if you could also post the plot pictures with what you tried, and what you don't like

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

df2 <-mtcars
df2 <- df2 %>% add_column(Cyl =
                          case_when(df2$cyl == 6 ~ "Six", 
                                    df2$cyl == 8 ~ "Eight",
                                    df2$cyl == 4 ~ "Four"), .after = "cyl")

mu_hp_cyl<- plyr::ddply(df2, "Cyl", summarise, grp.mean=mean(hp)) 
# head(mu_hp_cyl)

hp_cyl<-ggplot(df2, aes(x=hp, color=Cyl)) +
        geom_density()+
        geom_vline(data=mu_hp_cyl, aes(xintercept=grp.mean, color=Cyl),
                   linetype="dashed") +
        labs(x = 'Hp by Cylinder', y = 'Density')
hp_cyl + geom_text(data = mu_hp_cyl,
                   aes(grp.mean, 0.03, 
                   label = paste0("Mean: ", round(grp.mean, 2))),
                   angle = 90, vjust = 1.5)
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Use `theme(legend.position = c(0.9, 0.75))` to position the legend within the plotting area.